# Is MIT license suitable for an open source specification?

Tags: licensing, mit, specifications

I know the MIT license is suitable for code and its associated documentation.

However, is it suitable for an open source specification (without any code)? Or should I use a different license (and what license in that case)?

If I create an open source implementation of my specification, must I include both an MIT license for the code and the license of the specification I'm implementing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> must I include [...] an MIT license for the [...] license of the specification I'm implementing

Categorically, no. The license of the text of a specification has zero influence on the license of any implementations of the specification. You can have an GPL implementation of a proprietary specification, and you can have a proprietary implementation of a GFDL specification.

The only exceptions to this would be:

1. Patents.
2. Anything where you copy example code from the specification.

Comment: Patents are actually a very good reason to be discerning in your choice of license for the spec. For example, the Apache license might be a better choice than the MIT license, although it has the disadvantage of being substantially longer.